# unix time format in Mysql

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

Here I got a data like this: 1320609435.346877000, and I was told it was UNIX time which I do not understand. Shouldn't UNIX time look like an integer?

This data is stored in a txt as a column, if I want to insert this column into Mysql, which data type should I use and when I create a table, this default value should be assigned as NULL or ?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In MySql I always prefer using DATETIME type.
So you could use:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (your_col)
    SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(your_num)
```

See reference [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).
Unix time you posted (`1320609435.346877000`) is `2011-11-06 20:57:15`.